# How to transform some columns only with SimpleImputer or equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, imputation

I am taking my first steps with scikit library and found myself in need of backfilling **only** some columns in my data frame.

I have read carefully the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html) but I still cannot figure out how to achieve this.

To make this more specific, let's say I have:

```
A = [[7,2,3],[4,np.nan,6],[10,5,np.nan]]
```

And that I would like to fill in the second column with the mean but **not** the third.  How can I do this with SimpleImputer (or another helper class)?

An evolution from this, and the natural follow up questions is: how can I fill the second column with the mean and the last column with a constant (only for cells that had no values to begin with, obviously)?

Comment: Take a look at [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no need to use the SimpleImputer.
`DataFrame.fillna()` can do the work as well

- For the second column, use

  `column.fillna(column.mean(), inplace=True)`
- For the third column, use

  `column.fillna(constant, inplace=True)`

Of course, you will need to replace `column` with your DataFrame's column you want to change and `constant` with your desired constant.

---

**Edit**
Since the use of `inplace` is discouraged and will be deprecated, the syntax should be

```
column = column.fillna(column.mean())
```

Comment: That is really neat and clean.  It makes me wonder why bother with SimpleImputter at all.  Thank you!

Comment: pandas is really awesome for stuff like this

Comment: keep in mind that `inplace` will be deprecated in Pandas 2.0 so it might be best to explicitly assign.

Comment: Question asked for use of SimpleImputer or other classes. This answer can not be chained into a pipeline.

Comment: @gsandhu there is no mention of pipelines or classes in the original question.

Answer (score 11):

Following Dan's advice, an example of using `ColumnTransformer` and `SimpleImputer` to backfill the columns is:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

A = [[7,2,3],[4,np.nan,6],[10,5,np.nan]]

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
[('imp_col1', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'), [1]),
 ('imp_col2', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=29), [2])],
remainder='passthrough')

print(column_trans.fit_transform(A)[:, [2,0,1]])
# [[7 2.0 3]
#  [4 3.5 6]
#  [10 5.0 29]]
```

This approach helps with constructing [pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#) which are more suitable for larger applications.

Answer (score 2):

This is methode I use, you can replace `low_cardinality_cols` by cols you want to encode. But this works also justt set value unique to `max(df.columns.nunique())`.

```
#check cardinalité des cols a encoder
low_cardinality_cols = [cname for cname in df.columns if df[cname].nunique() < 16 and 
                        df[cname].dtype == "object"]
```

Why thes columns, it's recommanded, to encode only cols with cardinality near 10.

````
# Replace NaN, if not you'll stuck
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent') # feel free to use others strategy
df[low_cardinality_cols]  = imp.fit_transform(df[low_cardinality_cols])

# Apply label encoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
for col in low_cardinality_cols:
    df[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df[col])
    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have your data as a pandas dataframe.

In this case, all you need to do to use the `SimpleImputer` from scikitlearn is to pick the specific column your looking to impute nan's using say using the 'most_frequent' values, convert it to a numpy array and reshape into a column vector.

An example of this is,

```
## Imputing the missing values, we fill the missing values using the 'most_frequent'
# We are using the california housing dataset in this example
housing = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')
#Simple imputer expects a column vector, so converting the pandas Series
housing['total_bedrooms'] = imp.fit_transform(housing['total_bedrooms'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
```

Similarly, you can pick any column in your dataset convert into a NumPy array, reshape it and use the SimpleImputer